# Migrate data from Mysql to Mysql with Kettle Spoon changing Timezone

Tags: mysql, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I'm migrating and changing some data from one Mysql db to another Mysql db with a slightly different structure. The main difference is that on the first database dates are expressed in local timezone (Europe/Rome), instead on the target db they are UTC.
I'm sharing my db connection in all transformations.

I already made my transformations and everything works fine, but I didn't figure out a way to convert automatically all my dates in the right timezone. I was hoping to have something at connection level in order that all dates are automatically converted.
Otherwise I've add some extra transformation for every table and field (and they are many)!

I tried with the option `serverTimezone` at database level but it didn't work.

Does exist a smart way to do this conversion avoiding to add new transformations?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found the solution of my problem using the approach described from adamnyc [here](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/208186-How-to-get-UTC-date/).